# tracemalloc doesn't reflect memory usage of flask server?

Tags: flask, memory-leaks, tracemalloc

I have a memory leak in my flask server (it's a server that serve a tensorflow and a pytorch machine learning model). It has a dread memory leak.

So I use tracemalloc to track the memory. The problem is tracemalloc doesn't detect any memory leak. But It clearly show in the monitor that memory is leaked, also the memory detected in tracemalloc is much more smaller compare to what showned by htop ( a memory monitor tool ).

Why tracemalloc doesn't show all the memory use by flask, what did it miss? How did I make it show all the memory use by the process?